# How to show live log files generated by test framework during test execution through Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

Scenario - Using Jenkins For Test Execution. Test Generates Low Level Logs For Each Activity.
While Execution Is In Progress, We Want To See The Logs Being Updated

Problem Statement - How to see the logs like the way, we see console output On Jenkins

Solution Expected - To Have Something Like Console Outstreaming For File Streaming

The Solution - Post Build, Having Archieve Approach To View Files Is Not Solution

Comment: Can you redirect output of tests into console (and use `tee` if you still need file with log)?